# Sphere to plane collision

Tags: physics, computational-geometry

I could check for the distance of a vector from the sphere's center to the plane's center, but that would be inefficient, since there are multiple positions where they may not be intersecting but still are an "accepted" distance to flag a collision. I thought of two other methods (1) To get the distance between the center and all the vertices and (2) To have a normal on the plane get added to a vector between the plane's and sphere's centers, then check if the final point is in the sphere's radius and a certain distance from the plane, are these methods practical?

Comment: with plane do you mean the mathematical concept that goes infinitely or a flat piece of geometry bounded by 3 points

Comment: A flat piece of geometry that's three or four at least

Answer (score 2):

You're overcomplicating this.

```cs
public static float DistanceFromPlane(Vector3 testPoint, Vector3 pointOnPlane, Vector3 planeUnitNormal) {
    return Vector3.Dot(planeNormal, testPoint - pointOnPlane);
}
```

This works with any point on the plane, using the unit (length = 1) normal of the plane to extract only the perpendicular component of the distance.

This will return a signed distance value, with positive values on one side of the plane, negative on the other, and zero for points on the plane.

If the absolute value of this signed distance is equal to the sphere radius, the sphere is kissing the plane at one point. If it's less than the radius, the sphere intersects the plane. If it's greater than the radius, the sphere is wholly separated from the plane, and the sign tells you which side it's on.

You can do this a bit more efficiently if you express the plane as a 4-vector — then you only need one subtraction instead of three.

Comment: Did you mean vector3 dot?

Comment: Typo corrected.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, but I think you are referring to a plane defined by an equation, but I was more interested in a plane composed of vertices, I was also concerned what would happen if the sides had uneven lengths?

Comment: Then you should ask about a "polygon" not a "plane". Ask a precise question to get an accurately tailored answer.